# I get console warning "Possible unhandled promise rejection TypeError:0,_jwtDecode.default is not a function (it is undefined)"

Tags: javascript, react-native, jwt, token, decode

**I have installed and imported jwtDecode properly but why is there any error here is the code:-**
My jwtDecode doesn't seem to work i don't know the cause i have tried some sort of things i m new in react-native so please help and why is it not working

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useContext, useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { UserType } from '../userContext';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from '../Components/Users';

const Chat_feature = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { userId, setUserId } = useContext(UserType);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: '',
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingLeft: 4 }}>FRIENDS</Text>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', gap: 8, paddingRight: 4 }}>
          <Ionicons name="chatbox-ellipses-outline" size={24} color="black" />
          <MaterialIcons name="people-outline" size={24} color="black" />
        </View>
      ),
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('reached first');
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');
      
      console.log('Token:', token);
      console.log('reached second');

      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);

      console.log('reached third');

      const userId = decodedToken.userId;
      setUserId(userId);
      console.log('reached here');
      console.log('Fetching users...');
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/users/${userId}`).then((response) => {
        setUsers(response.data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error while retrieving users', error);
      });
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, [setUserId]);

  console.log('users=', users);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {users.map((item, index) => (
          <Users key={index} item={item} />
        ))}
      </View>
      <Text>Chat</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Chat_feature;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

**I tried importing jwtDecode in different ways like import * as jwtDecode, import {decode as jwtDecode} ....I expected my jwtDecode to run but it wasn't running that is why "reached third was not printing"**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of jwtDecode i used atob and that worked for me..here is the implementation

```
import { decode as base64decode } from 'base-64';

 global.atob = base64decode;


const decodedToken = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
```